# Does cordova android 4.1.0 support Android API level 23?

Tags: android, cordova

Does cordova android 4.1.0 support Android API level 23?

Android API level 23 removes the org.apache.http.* packages. But cordova is still using them. If I set android:targetSdkVersion=23 in my project's AndroidManifest.xml, will cordova run well on Android devices with API level 23?

Comment: just try it and let us know...

Comment: Just tried this and got [Error: Please install Android target: "android-22".

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, I know, but also set the API level in **platforms/android/project.properties** and **platforms/android/CordovaLib/project.properties**